# Continue to execute stored procedure after browser closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that sends an email to 20k and I am calling this from a .NET webpage which passes parameters to it. This takes sometime to send and if the page closes the sending stops.

I want to pass the parameters to the procedure and let it run until done.

Is the best way to do this to create an SSIS package and start that from the web page? If so, can I pass the parameters to the package and close the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I guess calling an SSIS package would still be synchronous. You need to decouple them and have them run asynchronously.

This looks like a good candidate for a Windows service. Your web page can set a flag that will drive the control logic for the service.

Otherwise simply set up an Sql agent job that polls the database for a give time interval and starts sending out email if the flag is set. And ofcourse set the flag from the web page. This will decouple them.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. How would I pass the parameters collected on the web page to the procedure if I used an agent job? Can I tart the job from the webpage?

Comment: Don't couple the job to the web page. The web page should only set a flag(bool field) in the database indicating there are emails to sent and when the Job runs the next time should check the flag and decide to send the email and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start SSIS jobs with a stored procedure asynchronously by creating a SqlAgent job that has an SSIS execution step and using [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).  [SSIS: Execute Package via Stored Procedure](http://sqlblog.de/blog/2009/09/ssis-execute-package-via-stored-procedure/) covers this option in a bit more detail.  If you go this route, I wouldn't attempt to pass parameters directly to the job (the only way I know to do that is to dynamically create the job).  Instead, I would simply insert some values into a database queue table, and have a single package that processes that queue.

You may also be interested in certain frameworks (such as [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)) that allow for running background tasks within asp.net.

[Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) is another popular framework for background jobs.

Scott Hanselman covers several of these options at [How to Run Background Tasks in asp.net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) (And be sure to note the ways in which Asp.net background tasks can fail, due to e.g. Application Pool recycling)

However, no matter what approach you take, you shouldn't assume that the job completed successfully - in other words, you need to maintain some kind of outgoing emails queue that will retry if a failure occurs.